# Is it good practice to use multiple stateful react hooks inside another hook to derive data?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, zustand, tanstackreact-query

I am currently working on a react native app using react query and zustand. The simplified version is a view that has a map. On top of the map is a bottom sheet which either shows a list of items or multiple screens using react navigation to add an item. I am persisting the state of each value in the form into a store using zustand. My list of items is fetched using react query. The map displays a location which either comes from the first item in the list or when the user chooses a location when adding a new item.

[image]

I am currently deriving the camera position of the map with a custom hook looking like this.

```
export const useMap = () => {
  const formLocation = useFormStore((state) => state.location);
  const { data } = useList();

  const currentCamera = {
    center: {
      latitude: 0,
      longitude: 0,
    },
    pitch: 0,
    heading: 0,
    altitude: 100000000,
    zoom: 0,
  };

  if (formLocation) {
    currentCamera.center = formLocation;
    currentCamera.altitude = 1000;
  }

  if (data && data.length > 0) {
    currentCamera.center = data[0].location;
    currentCamera.altitude = 1000;
  }

  return { currentCamera };
};
```

Since i normally only work with angular i am wondering if it is a good practice to compose hooks like this.

I feel like the state is pretty scattered. Since these hooks are only used for one screen i get the itch to colocate everything into one single hook.

Comment: What does `useList` look like? If you are just composing a convenience hook using other hooks, you should be fine. The only thing that would concern me is does `useMap` depend on the child components in a weird way.

Comment: Your code looks good (as far as we can tell without seeing `useList()`). Don't worry about spreading state across multiple hooks, in fact that's a good thing because you can reuse each hook independently.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the replies. useList ist just a wrapped useQuery from react query which fetches the list items.